# Stored Procedure output error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure has two cursors. 
The output of the stored procedure is in the following format.

```
companyid   companyname                                        id          idname                                             level3                                             level4                                             level5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         currency                                           accountdefinition                                  accname                                            accountno   debits                                  credits
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
101         Fund One Company                                   1001        Test Fund                                          Assets                                             Assets for PL Accounts                             NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               KWD                                                CA                                                 Current Account                                    NULL        NULL                                    NULL

(1 row(s) affected)

companyid   companyname                                        id          idname                                             level3                                             level4                                             level5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         currency                                           accountdefinition                                  accname                                            accountno   debits                                  credits
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
101         Fund One Company                                   1001        Test Fund                                          Assets                                             Assets for PL Accounts                             NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               KWD                                                CA                                                 Current Account                                    NULL        NULL                                    NULL

(1 row(s) affected)

companyid   companyname                                        id          idname                                             level3                                             level4                                             level5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         currency                                           accountdefinition                                  accname                                            accountno   debits                                  credits
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
101         Fund One Company                                   1001        Test Fund                                          Assets                                             Accounts for MM PL accounts                        NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               KWD                                                MPL                                                PL accounts for MM                                 NULL        NULL                                    NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Instead of showing all 3 rows as a single output. It is showing each row as a single output. This is causing an issue in the reporting level.

code:

```
alter  PROCEDURE TrialBalance
(
@companyid INT,   
@id    INT                --Input parameter ,  Studentid of the student
--@id VARCHAR(200)  OUT        -- Out parameter declared with the help of OUT keyword
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @level3 varchar(50),@level4 varchar(50),@level5 varchar(50),@level6 varchar(50),@level7 varchar(50),@level8 varchar(50),@level9 varchar(50),@level10 varchar(50),@level11 varchar(50),@rfrom int,@rto int,
@companyname varchar(50),@idname varchar(50),@accname varchar(50),@debits decimal(15,3),@credits decimal(15,3),@acno int,@acname varchar(25)
declare c cursor for SELECT 
level3,
level4,
level5,
level6,
level7,
level8,
level9,
level10,
level11,
rangefrom,
rangeto
from linedetails where level1 = @companyid and level2 = @id order by reportlineid

select @companyname = description from company where companycode = @companyid
select @idname = description from fundparameters where fundid = @id


open c
fetch next from c into @level3,@level4,@level5,@level6,@level7,@level8,@level9,@level10,@level11,@rfrom,@rto
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
select @accname = description from accounttype where accounttypeid = @level11
if @rfrom is not null and @rto is not null 
declare d cursor for select accountno,totaldebitslcy,totalcreditslcy from fund.dbo.account where (accountno >= @rfrom and accountno <= @rto) and currency = @level10
open d
fetch next from d into @acno,@debits,@credits
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
select @companyid as companyid ,@companyname as companyname ,@id as id ,@idname as idname,@level3 as level3 ,@level4 as level4,@level5 as level5,
@level6,
@level7,
@level8,
@level9,
@level10 as currency,
@level11 as accountdefinition ,@accname as accname,@acno as accountno, @debits as debits,@credits as credits
fetch next from d into @acno,@debits,@credits
end
close d
deallocate d
fetch next from c into @level3,@level4,@level5,@level6,@level7,@level8,@level9,@level10,@level11,@rfrom,@rto
end
end
close c
deallocate c
```

Comment: I presume you're doing the output from within the cursor loop ? this may explain that...

Comment: yes, is that an issue? How to do it otherwise?

Comment: Show the procedure, my magic 8-ball that shows me into your machine is broken this morning.

Comment: .... and Carnac says .....

Comment: You forgot to ask your question (even though we can guess what it would be). @Bartdude is probably spot-on. And post some code for crying out loud.

Comment: Done!! Posted the code guys. Sorry for asking the question

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write the question "how can I avoid using cursors here?", since none of the code seems to require cursors in any way.

Comment: that code if formated too poorly for me to waste my time looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your Select query in your nested cursor is selecting data from variables which can hold only single values at a time, so as the cursor iterates, the select statement returns a single tuple only for each iteration. Hence the output is logically correct.

The problem lies here:

```
select @companyid as companyid ,@companyname as companyname ,@id as id ,@idname as     idname,@level3 as level3 ,@level4 as level4,@level5 as level5,
@level6, @level7,@level8,@level9,Slevel10 as currency,@level11 as accountdefinition @accname as accname,@acno as accountno, @debits as debits,@credits as credits
```

Instead, create a table to temporarily hold your data from cursor and after your cursors iteration completes, select data from that table.

Instead of select, write an insert query like this:

```
insert into tmpTable values(@comapnyid,@companyname,@id,...etc);
```

And, just before the end of you procedure,

```
select * from tmpTable;
```

One more thing,

At the beginning of the SP, you might want to drop the tmpTable so that any already filled data in the table do not effect current values. like,

```
drop table tmpTable;
```

Comment: And by the way, you have to first create a tmpTable with the schema that you want in your output.

Comment: Thanks Amit for the explanation. Didnt really think that using cursors would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You make a SELECT in each run of your cursor loop. This results in one single select output per loop run.

If you want them all together declare a temporary table outside of the loop and insert your results into that during the loop.

Then select all contents of that temporary table after the loop is finished.